# Gettin an object from one class to another?

Tags: java, class, object, return

Need to bring the information from one class to the other, I need the final value of fin to return in getResultado.

```
public class Setter {
 String fin = "";
public  Setter(String result){
fin = result;
}
public String getResultado(String inicio){
return fin;
}
}
```

Here is the other class where I need to implement fin:

```
public Final(){
Setter t = getResultado();
    System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: `new Setter("XX").getResultado()`. You need some instance of Setter

Comment: Yeah, like @sidgate said, you need to create an instance of the object/initialize your reference. Right now, you just have a pointer with no value. You should be getting a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if I am not mistaken?

Comment: But this would change my outcome since I already have the established the value of fin with another Class.

Comment: @RudolfFanchini read my updated answer, that will explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is very simple: 
You never initialize an instance of your `Setter` class. You create a reference/pointer to a `Setter` object, but its `null` and you are trying to call a method contained in this class. So, you should probably be getting a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). The fix to this is simple, just

**initialize the object:**

`Setter t = new Setter("my string");`

**then call the method through your instance of Setter:**

`t.getResultado();`

**Edit:**
If you don't want to give the variable `fin` a value when you create an object `Setter`, just add a second constructor right underneath the first one like this:

```
public Setter() {
   //do whatever, maybe call the getResultado() method right here?
}
```

It will allow you to create Setter objects without any parameters or changing value of the variable.

Comment: but this would change my result, right? I already have another class that gives fin a value

Comment: Yes it would, what you would want to do for this is create a second constructor which takes no parameters.

Comment: So I change it to something like this:                                                     public class Setter {
     String fin = "";
public  Setter(String result){
    fin = result;
}
public void Setter(){
    
}
public String getResultado(String inicio){
   
    return fin;
}
}

Comment: @RudolfFanchini yes, except it shouldn't say public void Setter(){}, just public Setter() {}, its not a method returning a value, its a constructor for the object. I hope that helps!